# Regex to prohibit http or http://

Tags: regex

I am using fast secure contact form in my website. In all the fields like name, phone number, message, the back end allows regular expressions.

Right now I am having a problem with spam, getting a ton of spam. I noticed all the messages that come in contain a URL. so if I ban the string http or http:// I think that should stop the spam because legit messages never contain a URL.

I want the regular expression to act like this: If the message contains http then the message should not be sent. What would I enter in the Regex field for the message field to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you clarify what language you are using for the regex?

Answer (score 0):

To match (case-insensitively) only input *without* "http" anywhere in it:

```
^(?i)(?!.*http).*
```

If you wanted to be more precise, allowing `"http"` or `"https"`, but not when followed by `"://"`:

```
^(?i)(?!.*https?://).*
```

Which would allow text like "We specialize in https protocols", but still block links.

Comment: Thank you Bohemian, I will try those. And thanks for trying to be extra cautious, but I dont think anyone legit will ever use a phrase containing http iny my messages.

Comment: If you want to *match* bad input, change the `!` to `=`

Comment: So if I match, that means the message would go through only if it contains http? Also, I was gonna ask you, what if it's capitalized HTTP how can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: @LarryAntonio I've added the "case insensitive" flag to the regexes. A match with the regexes in the question means "it's not spam". If you replace '!' with '=' a match will mean "it's spam"

Comment: Bohemian, I just tried it and I got a 501 error saying something like "not supported" I think the i is not supported. How about banning http AND Http AND HTTP? I think that should do it.

Comment: What tool/language are you using? You may have to add it as an option, eg in JavaScript it would be `/^(?!.*http).*/i`

Comment: I think the fast secure contact form is run purely in php

Comment: @larry I'm pretty sure it's the options style, try the example in the previous comment verbatim

Comment: It did not work, the message still went through despite having http in it

Comment: @larry your tool may not support look aheads. Who knows. You'll have to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

If the assertions don't work for the engine you're using, there is an old
posix style trick you can try.

This only guards against `http:`. If you want to guard against `http://` add
the two extra `/` alternation sets for them.

`^(?:[^h]|http(?:[^:]|$)|htt(?:[^p]|$)|ht(?:[^t]|$)|h(?:[^t]|$))*$`

Expanded ( to see what it is )

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [^h]
   |  
      http
      (?: [^:] | $ )
   |  
      htt
      (?: [^p] | $ )
   |  
      ht
      (?: [^t] | $ )
   |  
      h
      (?: [^t] | $ )
 )*
 $
```

If your engine doesn't support case insensitive as well, this larger version
should work.

`^(?:[^hH]|[hH][tT][tT][pP](?:[^:]|$)|[hH][tT][tT](?:[^pP]|$)|[hH][tT](?:[^tT]|$)|[hH](?:[^tT]|$))*$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [^hH] 
   |  
      [hH] [tT] [tT] [pP] 
      (?: [^:] | $ )
   |  
      [hH] [tT] [tT] 
      (?: [^pP] | $ )
   |  
      [hH] [tT] 
      (?: [^tT] | $ )
   |  
      [hH] 
      (?: [^tT] | $ )
 )*
 $
```

Comment: I tried both. Neither works, the message is not sent whether or not it contains http. And there is an error message Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'h' in ...

Comment: @LarryAntonio - Post the code, big enough to reproduce, you've used where it shows that message. Sounds like a delimiter issue.

Comment: Thanks, I am using your larger code. I put a forward slash at the beginning of it and another forward slash at the end, and it seems to be working. Did I do anything wrong by putting the slashes? I don't know what I am doing and I just did it by intuition or coincidence.

Comment: @LarryAntonio  - If you've added delimiters (with quotes) then the _assertions_ should also work.